# Apple Sudden Motion Sensor and Hard Drive Upgrade

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro

I'm looking to upgrade a notebook hard drive and wanted to use the [Hitachi Travelstar 5K750](http://www.hitachigst.com/internal-drives/mobile/travelstar/travelstar-5k750). Will it work with the Apple Sudden Motion Sensor? Do I have any way of identifying drives that will play nice with this technology? I've heard of problems in the past, should I be concerned?

I'm running a Macbook Pro 13" (2009). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the drive doesn't have a sensor itself, there will be no problem.

If the drive has an acelerometer for detecting movement, them you must disable Apple's Sudden Motion Sensor, as described here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1934